# Get the video and audio PIDs for streams with ffprobe

Tags: ffprobe

It seems easy to SET the video/audio PIDs when transcoding with ffprobe, or to get only streams with a specific PID - all that is in the manual.

But I want to GET them from the stream. You can see them if you have text output, it is the hex code in square brackets at the start of the stream information of an actual ts segment. e.g.

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '/Users/development/Movies/OC3.demo.ts':
Duration: 00:09:32.72, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 13239 kb/s
Program 1
Metadata:
service_name    : Avalpa1: MPEG2 MHP
service_provider: Avalpa
Stream #0:0[0x810]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 2600 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

here `[0x810]`

Is there any way to get this videoPID in the `programs` or `streams` array entry of a probe of the master manifest? (when using the `-show_programs` and `-print_format json` options)

Comment: Not at this time; I''ve a dormant patch for this which I'll revive soon.

Comment: OK. I just manually parsed the text output, glad to know I didn't miss an option!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but ...
You should explicitly specify the input format. Ex:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -f mpegts -print_format json -show_streams rtp://239.25.67.1:1234
```

The result includes the PIDs as "id":

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
........
            "id": "0x100",
........
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "mp2",
            "codec_long_name": "MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
..........
            "id": "0x101",
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
.........
        }
    ]
}
```